# Uninstall package from @types in node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

I have library ('mime') in my node_modules, I want to uninstall this from my project including its @types files.
The reason I am doing this is I want to replace it with a new mime package as the old one doesn't work for me.

I tried to remove using npm uninstall mime. I even tried it with --save and --save-dev and also as Mime (Capitalized). I have also tried uninstalling from @types/mime directly. I want a working command for as deleting it directly sounds risky. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. npm was also useless here

Comment: I understood my problem, The mime type is actually a part of a package, So I will need to delete the entire package and wont be able to just get rid of Mime part of it. It kind of sucks how npm doesn't throw an error if something can't be uninstalled or is not a package. None of the above mentioned commands gave any error or warning.

Edit: I want to understand if there is two modules of the same name, how do I reference one in particular, I am not able to reference the new mime package. It keeps referencing the old one (thats part of a different package and not an entire package)

Comment: If the solution is help full for you can you please click up arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be issue of your node cache you can follow the below steps

1. First try the command npm uninstall @types/mime
2. Still it's not deleted then check your package.json file and remove that package name from your dependencies
3. If still not work then remove it from your node module folder
4. If still not work then clear your node cache.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the "@types/mime" (or any other typing) package directly is not a problem at all.

The types package is a dependency like any other and it was certainly installed separately as well.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is now that when I try to import mime it imports the old one from @types/mime, How do I change it?

Comment: Can you drop here the links of the packages you're talking about, just to be sure I understand all details? Which is the one current, which one is the old?

Comment: The old one: https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions/mime.d.ts

The one I want to reference: https://github.com/broofa/mime

I don't understand exactly but there might be some relation between them, I am not very good at dealing with node modules so apologies if I am confusing you

Comment: When I write import mime from 'mime' it references from @types/mime/index.ts (and this is the old one)
I want it to reference from node_modules/mime

Comment: Which version of this mime package are you using?